# Mysql query stress testing program

Tags: mysql, testing

We are writing queries for our website, and when we test the queries in a dev environment, the queries run pretty fast. The problem that we are having is the dev environment has less that 10 active users on it, while our live environment has 4,000+ simultaneous users and then our server just cant handle the queries.

So, is there a tool out there that can take some queries and do some stress testing on them, so we can test the queries before we put them live and kill the server?

Comment: You really need to expand on your question. Is your production server currently overloaded or are you writing software that will eventually go live? 4000 web users will not stress a properly indexed database. They can't click fast enough. Software does exist that does stress testing, but you're better off learning how to look at query plans while you're developing

Comment: The queries are fairly extensive, and the database is indexed properly. We are doing geo targeting with spatial indexes.

Comment: 4,000 is just a guess, I think our "Max connections" setting is set to something like 50,000. I just got 4k because that is what our process list was at, and they were all running the same thing. We have changed it and want to test. I did find `mysqlslap` though...

Comment: mysqlslap is the canonical answer. Best bet is to summon @RolandoMySQLDBA - he's a MySQL genius

Comment: @Phil thank you for the high regard. All the Percona guys have way more genuis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, you could go with mysqlslap.

If you are a little more adventurous, you may want to setup you own by deliberately dummying down the MySQL configurations or just collecting query profiles. Here are some of my posts and some of the others that address doing stress testing and query profiling. I hope the ideas help.

- `Apr 04, 2013` : [Stress test MySQL with queries captured with general log in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/stress-test-mysql-with-queries-captured-with-general-log-in-mysql)

  - [Accepted Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39226/877)
  - [My Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/39285/877)
- `Mar 10, 2013` : [Stress Test to Saturate Memory for MySQL InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36343/stress-test-to-saturate-memory-for-mysql-innodb)

  - [Accepted Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37193/877)
  - [My Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/37154/877)
- `Jun 08, 2012` : [How to improve MySQL Server Performance..??](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18975/how-to-improve-mysql-server-performance/18994#18994)
- `Dec 28, 2011` : [Is there a tool like Microsoft's "SQL Server Profiler" for MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9852/is-there-a-tool-like-microsofts-sql-server-profiler-for-mysql/9881#9881)
- `Jul 09, 2011` : [Testing Query Speed](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3742/testing-query-speed/3750#3750) (My Answer was MySQL-specific)

Give it a Try !!!